# Insert after dynamic parent div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, insert, insertafter

I'm trying to figure if it's possible to insert an element to load after a pop-up load.

I have 2 pop-ups. With an uploader element (I'm using an external library), the problem I'm having is that my uploader is loading before the pop-up.

The uploader works excellent when it's placed in the index page, but when it's in pop-up it doesn't load correctly.

My idea (I'm not sure that will work) but is to try load the uploader after the current parent div (if its index or popup).

The problem is my platform changes the pop-up id and class randomly every time the page loads so I need something that refers directly to current parent div.

I tried this:

```
const inputElement = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
const pond = FilePond.create( inputElement, fileOPs);
$("uploader").insertAfter(this);
```

also tried

```
$("uploader").insertAfter(this.div);
```

But no luck. Is there any way to do what I'm trying?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the code originates with an element that is not a `div` and you want to find the nearest ancestor `div`, use [`this.closest("div")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).

Here's an example (Vanilla JavaScript):

```js
document.getElementById("level3").addEventListener("click", function(evt){
  console.log(this.parentNode.closest("div").id);
});
```

```html
<div id="level1">
  <div id="level2">
    <span id="level3">Click Me</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

If the code originates with a `div` and you want to find the nearest ancestor `div`, use [`this.parentNode.closest("div")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).

Here's an example  (Vanilla JavaScript):

```js
document.getElementById("level3").addEventListener("click", function(evt){
  console.log(this.parentNode.closest("div").id);
});
```

```html
<div id="level1">
  <div id="level2">
    <div id="level3">Click Me</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For JQuery, you'd use the following regardless of what type of element the code originates from:

```js
$("#level3").on("click", function(evt){
  console.log($(this).closest("div").get(0).id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="level1">
  <div id="level2">
    <span id="level3">Click Me</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Once, you've referenced the correct element, you can insert the new node as needed.

Comment: Hello @Scott Marcus, thanks for your answer. I'm getting error using it like this: $(''uploader").insertAfter(this.parentNode.closest("div"));